# my register.blade don't seems to work in laravel 6 after i have added custom fields

Tags: php, laravel

I use the make:auth to create the register and login controller, then edited the form and validation correctly;

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required autocomplete="firstname" autofocus>

                                @error('firstname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="surname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Surname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('surname') is-invalid @enderror" name="surname" value="{{ old('surname') }}" required autocomplete="surname" autofocus>

                                @error('surname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sex" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Select Sex:') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="sex" class="form-control @error('sex') is-invalid @enderror" name="sex" value="{{ old('sex') }}" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Sex</option>
                                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                                </select>

                                @error('sex')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="country" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Select Country:') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="country" class="form-control @error('country') is-invalid @enderror" name="country" value="{{ old('country') }}" required>
                                  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 

                                </select>

                                @error('country')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phoneno" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone Number') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phoneno" type="tel" class="form-control @error('phoneno') is-invalid @enderror" name="phoneno" value="{{ old('phoneno') }}" required autocomplete="phoneno">

                                @error('phoneno')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I also edited the register controller and user.php correctly, but when I click on the submit button my form validate correctly but don't save or redirect me to the home blade
below is the register controller;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'sex' => ['required', 'string','max:8'],
            'country' => ['required', 'string','max:200'],
            'phoneno' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:11'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'surname' => $data['surname'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'sex' => $data['sex'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'phoneno' => $data['phoneno'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

the $fillable property in App/User.php

````
protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'surname', 'username', 'email', 'sex', 'country', 'phoneno', 'password',
    ];
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post  helpful in solving my issue  [Laravel custom authentication system](https://dev.to/sujithjr/laravel-custom-authentication-system-4e1a)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to add custom fields to your register form. Your code seems fine.

To make this work make sure you add these field in `$fillable` property in `app/User.php`

```
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password','firstname', 'surname', 'sex', 'country', 'phoneno'];
```

Comment: yes i want to add custom fields and I did edited the ```$fillable``` property in ``` app/User.php```

Comment: ```protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'surname', 'username', 'email', 'sex', 'country', 'phoneno', 'password'
    ];```

Comment: No it did not worked, I am also having the same issue with a similar project

Comment: run ` composer dump-autoload` then try